# afnetworking json into multi dimensional array

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Really struggling to figure this out. Just trying to take in data from php

```
curRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [curRow addObject:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"question"]];
    [curRow addObject:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"answers"]];
    [curRow addObject:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"correct_answer"]];
    [gameQuestions addObject:curRow];
```

in another method, I'm doing this

```
int i = arc4random() % [gameQuestions count];
CCLOG(@"Random: %i", i);

currentQuestion = [[gameQuestions objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0];
currentAnswer = [[gameQuestions objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1];
currentCorrectAnswer = [[gameQuestions objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:2];
CCLOG(@"question: %@", currentQuestion);
CCLOG(@"answer: %@", currentAnswer);
```

But when I look in the debug log, my question and answer are the same object?

```
2012-03-21 17:08:06.659 dunce[6849:707] Random: 0
2012-03-21 17:08:06.662 dunce[6849:707] question: (
    "Who was the 42nd president?",
    "What was the date that Microsoft released Windows 95?"
)
2012-03-21 17:08:06.666 dunce[6849:707] answer: (
    "Bill Clinton; Theodore Rosevelt; Barack Obama; Ronald Regan; ",
    "June 25th, 1994;September 3rd, 1992; August 24th, 1995; August 3rd, 1996"
)
```

i must be missing something

in php its just a simple while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $resultArr[$co]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $resultArr[$co]['question'] = $row['question'];
    $resultArr[$co]['answers'] = $row['answers'];
    $resultArr[$co]['correct_answer'] = $row['correct_answer'];
    $co++;
}

echo json_encode($resultArr);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Break the problem down. Does your PHP script appear to be producing correctly encoded JSON that has the data structured as you expect? On the Objective-C side, use the debugger at various places to see if the data you're assigning to your various arrays actually makes sense. 99 times out of 100, if you take things one step at a time and actually inspect what's going on, you can solve your own problems.

Comment: I know. The problem is learning where the problem is. Coming from PHP, Obj-C is a different world to me. But, I'm trying...

Comment: every problem i run into i try to think of how i would solve it in PHP, then translate it to obj-c. i should have known i'd have to iterate through the result. just thought afnetworking would give it to me that way for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got it.

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    for(id entry in JSON)
    {
        NSMutableArray *curRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [curRow addObject:[entry valueForKeyPath:@"question"]];
        [curRow addObject:[entry valueForKeyPath:@"answers"]];
        [curRow addObject:[entry valueForKeyPath:@"correct_answer"]];
        [gameQuestions addObject:curRow];
        [curRow release];
        curRow = nil;            
    }
```

Comment: Great, this helped me out a lot :)